# why doesn't jquery confirm modal work on my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

can someone please tell me why is the jquery confirm modal doesn't work on my app?
here's my code

```
        <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
        </div>
```

here's the js code

```
 if(userid == ""){
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

there's no pop-up that come out, but when i tried the simple modal alert, it works

i have this in my header

```
jquery-ui.min.js
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sQhgQ/ - your code is working well, I see the dialog window.

Comment: you should have jquery-min also in your header, not just the ui.
unless you did a custom pack.

Comment: i have the jquery min also..still investigating why confirm pop up doesn't appear

Comment: I removed the buttons. that's the only time the pop up appeared, any idea why the buttons is causing it not to appear ?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI? Is there no errors in console?

Comment: yes there's no error at the console at all, but i still wonder why the confirm pop up wont show up if i didn't commented the buttons param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by including the dependency js files ROFL